# PATH issues with gitlab-runner on centos 8

Tags: centos, gitlab, centos8

I'm having an issue when trying to use the gitlab runner I installed in my centos 8 server.

So here are the details:

I followed the instructions here to install: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html

I downloaded and installed their rpm package then ran it and registered it, using the `shell` executor

So far so good.

The issue is that when the runner tries to run a pipeline, I get this error:

`ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Failed to start process: exec: "su": executable file not found in $PATH`

There is a similar issue with the runner on nixOS, apparently, but I'm unsure how I would apply the workaround.

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/53985

So I'm unsure whether I messed something up during install at some point or not; and whether I can fix it or apply a workaround, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe SELinux is enabled by default.
Test with `getenforce` or `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log` on gitlab-runner

That was my Problem with RHEL8 and gitlab-runner.

You can temporary disable SELinux with `setenforce 0` and try to run CI/CD job again.

After disabling SELinux or adding the missing rules it works fine for me.

Comment: I get the same problem. Not wanting to disable SELinux I have been adding rules. So far I have added 5 rules. Where will it ever end? I'm searching for a root cause.